# Notice: Undefined variable: x in include()

Tags: php

I used ternary operators to have multiple backgrounds with listed item.

But now I am getting this error, Error message

> Notice: Undefined variable: x in include() (line 45 of
>   /home/content/67/11380467/html/beta/sites/all/modules/custom/blogs.tpl.php).

```
<?php 

    $x++;   
    $class = ($x%2 == 0)? 'second': '';
    print $class; 

?>
```

Can you please help me understand what went wrong here and help me fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: error says $x is undefined try to define the `$x=0` before increment

Comment: There isn't an `include()` statement here. can you show more context which includes the `include()` call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$x` is undefined. You can't do `$x++` when you didn't define it yet. You probably need to add this in front:

```
$x = 0;
```

This is assuming you want to start at `0`

Answer (score 2):

Declare

```
$x = 0; before $ x++; first
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `$x++` as the included file doesn't know about `$x` assuming you have declared it somewhere else.

if you haven't declared `$x` anywhere, then it is probably a good idea to declare it `$x = 0;`

Alternatively, you can ignore the Notice and everything should work fine because PHP is a weakly typed language, it will auto-initialize it, but in general it is bad practice to depend on something like that. Notices are not necessarily a bug, but they usually point to one.